# Access same data through 3 different activities

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I'm new to android development but I give my best.

I want to create an app for scoring a card game for 2 teams playing:

Activity1: Make your bid
Activity2: Evaluate the outcome of the game
Activity3: Show a list with the score of the teams (2 columns)
Start over with Activity1 until someone has won.

So I have activity1 passing data to activity2 (using putExtra with an intent)
Activity2 evaluated the bid and calculates the score of Team1 and Team2.
That data is being passed to activity3.

Here I would like to Show a list with the scores of every round.

But where / how do I save that list data when I move on to activity1 again?

I'm already playing around with a new class which should be extending the application but I do not know how to instantiate that class and how to make it accessible form each activity?

Here is my manifest.xml => extradata as a new class:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/notrump"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="extradata">
    <activity
```

This class is set up like this:

```
public class extradata extends Application{

public static ArrayList<scoredata> scoring = new ArrayList<scoredata>();

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
}
```

And the scoredata class looks like that:

```
public class scoredata {

private int mScoreteam1;
private int mScoreteam2;
private String mBidteam1;
private String mBidteam2;


public scoredata(int pScoreteam1, int pScoreteam2, String pBidteam1, String pBidteam2){
    mScoreteam1 = pScoreteam1;
    mScoreteam2 = pScoreteam2;
    mBidteam1 = pBidteam1;
    mBidteam2 = pBidteam2;
}

public int getScoreteam1(){
    return mScoreteam1;
}

public int getScoreteam2(){
    return mScoreteam2;
}

public String getBidteam1(){
    return mBidteam1;
}

public String getBidteam2(){
    return mBidteam2;
}

public void setScoreteam1(int pScoreteam1){
    mScoreteam1 = pScoreteam1;
}

public void setScoreteam2(int pScoreteam2){
    mScoreteam2 = pScoreteam2;
}

public void setBidteam1(String pBidteam1){
    mBidteam1 = pBidteam1;
}

public void setBidteam2(String pBidteam2){
    mBidteam2 = pBidteam2;
}
```

So do I now have an arraylist of scoredata created when the application starts?
And if so how do I access the fields or add an item from my activities?

Comment: Where do you have the problem ? The best thing to get helpful answers is to post the code you have and state the exact problem with your code.

Comment: I do not know how to add the latest score every time I start the activity. How do I save the date of the listview when I leave activity3 and go to activity1 - to activity2 and back to activity3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to pass the new added values from activity2 to activity1 you can use intents.
Call second activity using startactivityforesult(intent,requestcode).  After getting the new values pass the result from activity 2 using setresult().

[use this link](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example)

Update your arraylist(i.e. add new item) in onActivityResult() function inside activity1.
Use  adapter.setnotifychanged to make the updates reflect in listview.

Comment: My problem is, that after each round of playing I get 2 new scores - one for each team. So I need an ArrayList which grows every round and then update my ListView

Answer (score 0):

You may want to implement a class as a datastore, and make it a singleton so each of your 3 activities can access the data and modify it. 
I don't know if it's the best solution for your problem but it's a simple one.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a link to some sample for using a singleton in android?

Comment: The singleton is a well-known pattern, you shouldn't have any trouble finding detailed descriptions. The fact that you want to use it with Android doesn't make any difference, just find an example in Java (even the wikipedia page has one).